# How to create Kafka consumer groups?

Tags: ruby, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I'm new to Kafka.  I'm trying to implement a simple queueing system using 1 topic and 1 consumer group assigned to that topic.  However I couldn't figure out how to create a consumer group.

p.s. I'm using Ruby, with the kafka-rb gem.

Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** we (Zendesk) have since released [Racecar](https://github.com/zendesk/racecar), a simplified Kafka consumer framework built on top of ruby-kafka.

A Racecar consumer would look like this:

```
# simple_consumer.rb
class SimpleConsumer < Racecar::Consumer
  subscribes_to "some-topic"

  def process(message)
    puts message.value
  end
end
```

In order to run it, simply execute the following:

```
$ gem install racecar
$ racecar --require my_consumer MyConsumer
```

Read more on Github: https://github.com/zendesk/racecar

Original post:

---

Here's how you'd do it in [ruby-kafka](https://github.com/zendesk/ruby-kafka):

```
require "kafka"

kafka = Kafka.new(seed_brokers: ["kafka1", "kafka2"])
consumer = kafka.consumer(group_id: "my-group")

consumer.subscribe("my-topic")

consumer.each_message do |message|
  puts message.value
end
```

See also the [README](https://github.com/zendesk/ruby-kafka#consumer-groups) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing, and I don't think that it's actually part of Kafka, but rather something that the Java driver does in conjunction with ZooKeeper. If you read the design docs for Kafka 0.7 (http://kafka.apache.org/07/design.html), there's a section toward the bottom titled "Consumers and Consumer Groups" where they talk about it a bit. It makes sense, since ZooKeeper could easily be used to track the latest offset for a group of consumers.

Answer (score 1):

if u look at the configuration of kafka consumer (http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html), `group.id` is a unique string that identifies the consumer group this consumer belongs to. 
**By default, it is ""**

It seems that `kafka-rb` did not provide a way to do it.
but some other gem can help u to do that like 
https://github.com/zendesk/ruby-kafka#consumer-groups 
https://github.com/karafka/karafka#group